# Does flask_login automatically set the "next" argument?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I've created a login and logout page using Flask Login. I'm trying to navigate to the logout page without logging in first, but I keep getting redirected here: http://127.0.0.1:5000/login?next=%2Findex

Here's my logout function:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request
from app import app
from app.forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm
from flask_login import current_user, login_user, logout_user, login_required
from app.models import User
from app import db

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redirecting to a view that requires the user to be logged in hence the reason the `next=` value is set.

```
@app.route('/')
@login_required # <-- Your index view has this.
def index():
    return 'Index'
```

Redirect users to a page that doesn't require one to be logged in or one without the `@login_required` decorator when they log out.

Comment: Yes, I do have that at the index page. But, why does that affect the logout page?

Comment: @Bob What is the end result of logging out? Being redirected to a view called `index`. Can you access it with the `@login_required` decorator? No, you need to be logged in and yet you just logged out. So `flask-login` redirects you to the log in page, once you log in it redirects you to the `index` view that you wanted to access despite having logged out.

Answer (score 1):

When a user that is not logged in accesses a view function protected with the @login_required decorator, the decorator is going to redirect to the login page, but it is going to include some extra information in this redirect so that the application can then return to the first page. If the user navigates to /index, for example, the @login_required decorator will intercept the request and respond with a redirect to /login, but it will add a query string argument to this URL, making the complete redirect URL /login?next=/index. The next query string argument is set to the original URL, so the application can use that to redirect back after login.

Check:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins